# JavaScript number formatting with point for thousand and comma for decimals

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a web application with some calculations in text fields. Application is worked in asp.net using vb. I have JavaScript that need to do some calculations every time onTextChange action.

For example I have to enter a number in this format 123.123 or 123 and at the end I want to calculate all text fields and to do formatting like this 123.123,00 or 123,00

For now I am using:

```
document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl("txtSUM").ClientID%>').value = ("" + sum).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, function ($1) { return $1 + "." });
```

but this only adding a point on thousand, apart from that I want to add and comma on decimal place.

Comment: Try using [numeraljs](http://numeraljs.com/) or simply [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: Thank you a lot Hearty. I am using this in my case number.toLocaleString('de-DE');